# Why do I get relative import error in python?

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror

I'm having this issue in python with relative imports, when I want to import a file from another folder I get an error.

File structure:

```
python/
  helpers/
    index.py
  posts/
    post.py
```

Then, I do in the `posts/post.py` file:

```py
from ..helpers.index import conn
```

But when I run the python file, I get this error:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong. Especially that `vscode` understands that I'm trying to import this file

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer might be helpful: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912)

In the section titled "Relative imports".